# How to print an array of structs, recursively?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, struct

I have this array with 100 movies (struct Movie, I got the data from a previously loaded simply linked list), and for some reason when I try to print the content (in this case, just the title of the movie) it only shows 45 movies out of the 100. And then the program stops.
It's part of a bigger code, but the rest works fine so I'm gonna post the code that I have problems with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

// List of movies
struct Node{
    Movie movie;
    struct Node *next; 
};

// Pointer to the first element of the list
typedef struct{
struct Nodo *head;
}List;

typedef struct{
    int id;
    char title[100];
    char director[100];
    char genre[100];
    int likes;
    int number_of_voters;
    float rating;
    int year;
    int cost;
    char color[100]; // "Color" or "BW"
}Movie;

typedef struct{
     Movie movies[SIZE];
     int cant; // Number of structs loaded
}Array;

void Initialize(List *l);
void FromListToArray(List l, Array *arr);
void PrintArray(Array arr, int length);

int main(){
    List list;  // Previously loaded with movies, which I copied from a txt file
    Array a;
    Initialize(&list);
    FromListToArray(list, &a);
    // Array previously loaded with 100 movies (index 0 to 99), so a.cant = 100
    int length = a.cant - 1;
    PrintArray(a, length)
    return 0;
}

void PrintArray(Array arr, int length){
    if (lenght < 0){    // Base
        return;
    }
    // Inductive
    printf("%s\n", arr.movies[length].title);
    PrintArray(arr, sup-1);
}

/* Initializes a simply linked list */
void Initialize(List *l){
    (l->head) = NULL;
}

/* Copies the data of "colored" movies (there are black and white movies too in the list) from a simply linked list into an array */
void FromListToArray(List l, Array *arr){
    int i = 0;
    arr->cant = 0;
    struct Node *p;
    p = l.head;
    while ((p->next != NULL) && (arr->cant < SIZE)){
        if (strcmp(p->movie.color, "Color\n")==0){
            // Copy the content of the movie from the list into the array
            arr->movies[i].id = p->movie.id;
            strcpy(arr->movies[i].title, p->movie.title);
            strcpy(arr->movies[i].director, p->movie.director);
            strcpy(arr->movies[i].genre, p->movie.genre);
            arr->movies[i].likes = p->movie.likes;
            arr->movies[i].number_of_voters = p->movie.number_of_voters;
            arr->movies[i].rating = p->movie.rating;
            arr->movies[i].year = p->movie.year;
            arr->movies[i].cost = p->movie.cost;
            strcpy(arr->movies[i].color, p->movies.color);
            arr->cant++;
            i++;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    printf("Movies in the array ::: %d\n", arr->cant);
}
```

Comment: It's good that you have tried to minimise the code for us. But it also needs to be complete. Otherwise it's often the case that the actual code that causes the problem is removed (because by definition you don't know where the problem is). For example, in this case we don't know what the value of `a.cant` is. You say it's 100 but we need to see the actual code to verify that. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe it's a stackoverflow... would be pretty reasonable, considering a stack usage of more than `100*400` char per recursion call of `PrintArray`. You probably want to pass `Array` by reference (pointer) to the `PrintArray` function, or dynamically allocate the `movies` within.

Comment: Similar to what @grek40 said. Using recursion for something like `PrintArray` is not a good idea. Each recursive call uses up part of the stack and is likely to lead to overflow as the array length increases (if it hasn't already overflowed with your current 100 size). A simple loop would work much better here. Unless of course you are required to do that as part of the assignment/question.

Comment: @kaylum I'm required to use recursion for this.
So the problem is that it overflows with data and kills the process?

Comment: Alright guys, I did what you said and it works.
So it would be void PrintArray(Array *arr, int length) and printf("%s\n", arr->movies[length].title);

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue was already resolved in comments, this is a quick wrap-up of the problem and solution.

#### Analysis

You created a recursive function that should reach a recursion depth of 100. Instead, at some 40 recursive calls, the program crashes with a stackoverflow.

Since the stack should typically provide at least 1mb of space, you can assume that *something* is occupying much more stack space per recursive call than what you assumed. Stack is mostly occupied by local variables and function parameters.

In your case, `PrintArray` doesn't define any local variables within the function, so the function parameters are the most likely culprit.

The `Array` parameter reserves stack space according to the struct size for each recursive call, since the parameter is taken by value, rather than by reference (pointer).

The `Array` struct size is quite large, since it contains an array of 100 elements, where each element consists of a struct `Movie`, which in turn contains 4 char arrays of size 100 each, among other properties. So, ignoring the other properties and all alignment extra space, the size of `Array` can be abstracted as `100 elements * 4 arrays * 100 characters each => 40000 char`.

So, for each recursive call, more than 40000 byte are copied to the next stack segment. Inflating this by 40 recursive calls gives `40000 * 40 = 1600000 bytes` which is 1.5mb plus (remember, I'm being **very** inaccurate here...) in required stack size.

#### How to fix

Typically, this kind of task would be performed iteratively in a loop - you mentioned you can't do that due to specific constraints of your task.

As mentioned in the comments, the problem goes away by replacing the `Array` parameter by a pointer type `Array*` and changing the usage accordingly. Since the function only ever reads from the array, I would recommend making the parameter `const Array*`.

Even with the pointer, stack space is reserved for each parameter for each recursive call. But now the amount of required space is determined by the size of the pointer (4-8 bytes typically), the `length` parameter and some internal values like the return address. So the `arr` parameter space requirement decreased by a factor of at least 5000 (but the overall stack usage decreased by a bit lower factor).

The decreased size requirement means, you should now be able to print your list of 100 items, but it also means that you are likely to run into the same problem again, if your list contains a few thousand instead of a few hundred items.

#### Side Notes (might be irrelevant)

Your `length` parameter doesn't do what the name promises. It is not used as a length information. Instead it is used as a last accessable index. Variable names should be consistent with their content / usage.

It seems you print your array back-to-front.

In function `FromListToArray`, you loop on the condition `p->next != NULL`. This looks suspicious for two reasons:

1. if the list is empty and `p` is NULL you probably run into trouble
2. the last element `p` is not processed in the loop, just because it doesn't have a successor.